# Where can I find the dict_keys class?

Tags: python, python-3.x

How can I get a reference directly on the `dict_keys` class?  Currently the only way I could find is by creating a temporary dict object and type-checking it.

```
>>> the_class = type({}.keys())
>>> the_class
<class 'dict_keys'>
>>> the_class.__module__
'builtins'
>>> import builtins
>>> builtins.dict_keys
AttributeError: module 'builtins' has no attribute 'dict_keys'
```

Comment: On Python 2 it is a `list`.

Comment: @PeterWood: Yes, but `dict_keys` still exists there, with instances returned from `dict.viewkeys`, which is behaves much like Py3's `dict.keys`.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

That's how you're "supposed" to do it, though the only reason I've ever bothered is to fix a bug in Py 2.7 where `dict_keys` wasn't a virtual subclass of `collections.KeysView`, and I used that technique to do what Py3 does by default.

When `collections.abc` (implemented in Python, not C) [registers the type](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/v3.5.0/Lib/_collections_abc.py#l655) as a virtual subclass of `collections.abc.KeysView`, [it does](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/v3.5.0/Lib/_collections_abc.py#l49):

```
dict_keys = type({}.keys())
... many lines later ... 
KeysView.register(dict_keys)
```

because the class isn't otherwise exposed at the Python layer. I figure if Python itself has no better way to accomplish the task, it's probably the right way to do it. Of course, you could always borrow the fruits of Python's labor:

```
# Can't use collections.abc itself, because it only imports stuff in
# _collections_abc.__all__, and dict_keys isn't in there
from _collections_abc import dict_keys
```

But given that `_collections_abc` is undocumented (aside from a link to the source code in [the `collections.abc` documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.abc.html), which I doubt constitutes a binding contract to preserve it), I'd stick to `dict_keys = type({}.keys())` (which doesn't rely on any undocumented behaviors), or when you're performing `isinstance`-based type-checking, use [`collections.abc.KeysView`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.abc.html#collections.abc.KeysView) instead.

Comment: Are you sure the suggestion to use `collections.abc.KeysView` in `isinstance()` for detecting objects of type dictionary  keys is correct? Won't `isinstance()` trigger `True` for non-dictionary objects supporting the `.keys()` method? See : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76888283/python-3-11-how-to-directly-specify-the-type-of-being-member-of-the-class-dict for details.

Comment: @Claudio: It will return `True` for the return value from a non-dictionary object *on which you have called `.keys()`* which itself adheres to the same contract a `dict`'s `dict_keys` object adheres to. It won't return true for objects that happen to have a `.keys()` method, nor for the return value from that method, *unless it is usable as a keys view*. If it must be *exactly* a `dict_keys` object, sure, you can use `type(myobj) is type({}.keys())`, but usually knowing it claims to adhere to the `KeysView` contract is enough, no need to exclude custom classes that still do what you want.

Comment: To be clear, if I really needed to check in a type strict way, I'd do `dict_keys = type({}.keys())` once at global scope to avoid creating new `dict`s and `dict_keys` objects for each type check, but I have *never* needed type strict checking, and rarely even cared if it's `KeyView`-like; all I've ever needed is to know if it adheres to the   `Set` contract.

Comment: Thanks for the fast response :). Maybe it is a good idea to update the answer with what you stated in your replies to my query about your answer? This would make this comments obsolete, so that they could be deleted and it would improve the answer, wouldn't it?

Comment: In other words, your answer is still up-to-date and valid also for Python 3.11 and 3.12?

Comment: @Claudio: Yep, and I don't foresee that changing. The nitty-gritty implementation detail types aren't exposed because: 1) There's no obvious place to put them (they shouldn't bloat the built-in scope, and no module makes particular sense for it), and 2) Basically no idiomatic Python-level code should ever care about it, and non-idiomatic code can always do non-idiomatic things (like `type({}.keys())`) if they truly need it.

Comment: Thanks again for the fast response. I would be glad if you may take a look at my latest question here helping me with understanding some basic things about Python: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76885085/explanation-of-python-behavior-for-exectextwithfunctionname-in-combination-wit . Thanks in advance for your attention.